# How to write dockerfile for image based gitlab-ci file so that i can reuse in quality-check stage which is build in build-phase?

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile, gitlab-ci

#### Stages for gitlab-ci.yml file

- Stage=>Build_image, job::build_image => which will also build the project
- Stage=>Quality_Check, job::test_junit, job::lint_pmd, job::test_jacoco
- Stage=>Deploy, job::deploy_services

  #### Dockerfile need to be build in a way that i can run cmmands like mvn test,lint,jacoco coverage,etc too can run from the built image
- This i need to make for java project which uses maven as respository to download dependenies

Comment: Can you tell us what you already tried?

Comment: @Jonathan i am facing problem in writing dockerfile i have written basic dockerfile with multi stage build.Now i have to modify this dockerfile in such a way that after build image from dockerfile when  i pull image from registry i can run commands like mvn test,mvn pmd:check .The dockerfile i build consist of only building jar of service and dockerizing to it .